# Cannot install packages using pip

Tags: python, pip

When i tried to install openCV using pip3 install opencv-python i got this error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python

i have tried upgrading pip using

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

none of them helped me and pip is up to date
tried to download and compile opencv manually gives me bunch of errors

```
python version -2.7,3.6.2

pip version- up to  date

raspberry pi 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this information means that your python version or OS version not compatible with any openCV version which pip can find on the internet.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

So, please check your python version (include 32bit or 64bit) and OS type, version, and then try pip again.
I use python3.6.5 32bit(virtualenv), windows 10 64bit install openCV succeed.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ says: "Note that the wheel (especially manylinux) format does not currently support properly ARM architecture so there are no packages for ARM based platforms in PyPI. However, opencv-python packages for Raspberry Pi can be found from https://www.piwheels.org/."